# How can I make a series of steps for a progress bar in a multi-step form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have the following code

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class='progress-bar bar-style' role='progressbar' aria-valueactive='1' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax="8" id='userProgress'>
       <span id="progressStatus"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It produces a basic static nav that updates where I want and I am modifying the inside `span` with JS.

I want to build a label on top that shows the following:

- Step 1: Setup
- Step 2: Input Config
- Step 3: Output Header
- Step 4: Output Zip

The purpose is to be a static header over the progress bar of a multi-step form. 
Issue is I have no idea how to code this, or how to even start. Bootstrap-3 doesn't seem to have any simple snippets for how to make one.

I'd assume I'd have some means of adding text above the nav and javascript change which text is highlighted on  form navigation? Can anyone share any links or point in the direction of some documentation to get started?

Comment: you can try this example https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can try bootstrap multistep form example

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #6441A5; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5, #2a0845); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    background: transparent;
}

/*form styles*/
#msform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}

/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#msform input:focus, #msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ee0979;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #ee0979;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #ee0979;
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    width: 100px;
    background: #C5C5F1;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover, #msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #C5C5F1;
}

/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none;
}

/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #ee0979;
    color: white;
}


/* Not relevant to this form */
.dme_link {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dme_link a {
    background: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ee0979;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dme_link a:hover, .dme_link a:focus {
    background: #C5C5F1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- MultiStep Form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form id="msform">
            <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
                <li>Social Profiles</li>
                <li>Account Setup</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us something more about you</h3>
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter"/>
                <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook"/>
                <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill in your credentials</h3>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <!-- link to designify.me code snippets -->
        <div class="dme_link">
            <p><a href="http://designify.me/code-snippets-js/" target="_blank">More Code Snippets</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.link to designify.me code snippets -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
```